# Electrum: get transaction confirmations

Tags: electrum, transaction-selection

I need to get transaction confirmations via command line. But seems there is no such method. `onchain_history` seems returns information but I don't want to pull a whole history, I need info about one transaction only not all. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_tx_status('TXID')
```

Replace TXID with transaction id.

```
>> get_tx_status('c12ed68e512aa68dbf88878902efba20446024b645f5254f4b9411db2c6e684c')
{
    "confirmations": 589
}
```

The transaction should be associated with your wallet else you will get below error:

`Exception: Transaction not in wallet.`